# How to assign Public IP to Kubernetes's Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kong, kubernetes-helm

I have deployed **Kong-Ingress-controller** using **helm**

And I have Kubernetes's Cluster v1.10 On centos 7

I am using dedicated Server From OVH Provider

When I create Ingress

```
cat ingress.yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: jenkins 
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: jenkins
    servicePort: 8080
```

---

```
kubectl get ing
NAME      HOSTS     ADDRESS   PORTS     AGE
jenkins   *                   80        3s
```

---

```
kubectl get svc
NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
jenkins                ClusterIP   10.254.104.80   <none>        8080/TCP         1d
```

Now I Can not access this Ingress from Out Side because I am using OVH Server.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OVH is not [officially supported by Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/). It was supported then generally you would create a Service `jenkins` of the type `LoadBalancer` and that would be your externally facing endpoint with a public IP.

Since it's not supported the next best thing is to create a `NodePort` service. That will create a service that listens on a specific port on all the Kubernetes nodes and forwards the requests to your Pods (only where they are running). So, in this case, you will have to create an [OVH Load Balancer](https://www.ovh.com/world/solutions/load-balancer/) with a public IP and point the backend of that load balancer to the `NodePort` of the service where your `Ingress` is listening on.

Comment: Can you Sir see this https://labs.ovh.com/kubernetes-k8s , and I am waiting Your comment :D

Comment: Yes, you can run in the ovh cloud but Kubernetes doesn't have a direct plugin solution for an external load balancer yet.

Comment: Okay , Thank You :D